# CMakeLists.txt files for multiple libraries and executables

Tags: cross-platform, cmake, cross-compiling

I am just starting playing with CMake. I have something like:

```
/DEV
 |-- lib1
        | CMakeLists.txt

 |-- lib2
        | CMakeLists.txt

 |-- exe1
        | CMakeLists.txt

/BUILD
 |-- lib1
 |-- lib2
 |-- exe1

/INSTALL
 |-- include
 |-- lib
 |-- bin
```

I would like to:

- Build each lib and exe independently when needed. (So I suppose I must add a CMakeLists.txt file for each lib and exe);
- When building, include and lib directories should reference INSTALL directory; (is it a good idea?)
- When building, add dependencies to other lib and rebuild them if not up to date.

I dont have any clue where to start. Please help...

Comment: In addition to arrowdodgers excellent answer: Build a single lib, exe independently can also be done by cd'ing into the generated build-dir for that lib and call make/msbuild. E.g. with visual studio, cmake will generate a solution file for each lib/exe if that lib/exe has its own CMakeLists.txt with a project() command

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need individual CMakeLists.txt to build targets independently.  Say you have one top level CMakeLists.txt with:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib1 ${all_lib1_files})
ADD_LIBRARY(lib2 ${all_lib2_files})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(exe1 ${all_exe1_files})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib2 lib1)  # lib2 now depends on lib1
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exe1 lib2)  # exe1 now depends on lib2 and lib1
```

Then you can build just lib1 by running `make lib1` or `msbuild lib1.vcxproj`, etc.  You can achieve the same by having individual CMakeLists.txt files per target - it's up to you if you think it's worth it.

If your project imports these targets using `FIND_LIBRARY` or `FIND_PACKAGE`, then they **won't** be rebuilt if they're not up to date.  Ultimately, if you want out-of-date dependencies to be automatically rebuilt, you need to let CMake know about the sources and rules for the dependent target, i.e. the CMakeLists.txt file needs to have added the target using `ADD_LIBRARY` or `ADD_EXECUTABLE`.

You shouldn't then need to reference the INSTALL directory (except in `INSTALL` commands I imagine), since CMake will implicitly use libs/exes build locations rather than installed locations when linking targets.

Comment: seems a better solution to me. Must I put the CMakeLists.txt file at the top level or could I put such a file in each executable folder? Or is there some "recursive magic" I should take into account? Thanks!

Comment: It's normal to have your main CMakeLists.txt in your project's root.  If you want, you can add CMakeLists.txt files to each exe folder and then just `INCLUDE` each of these.  `INCLUDE` runs the commands inline, so there's no need for these subordinate CMakeLists.txt files to be fully standalone (i.e. they don't need the `PROJECT` command, etc.), they'd just be a way of achieving separation of the different parts of the project and keeping the top-level file cleaner.  Each could have just `SET(all_exe1_files ...)`, `ADD_EXECUTABLE(exe1 ${all_exe1_files})` and `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(exe1 ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

To

> Build each lib and exe independently when needed.

just add `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` keyword into `add_executable()` or `add_library()` calls.

> When building, include and lib directories should reference INSTALL
>   directory

If by `referencing` you mean adding it to `include_directories()` and `link_directories()` then it's not nice. It's better not to assert on location of needed files on user system. The proper way is to locate needed includes and libraries using `find_package()`, `find_library()` or `find_file()`. If you want to use first function, you would need to write `FindYourLib.cmake` and install it along library itself.

> When building, add dependencies to other lib and rebuild them if not
>   up to date

This is done automatically by CMake. Dependencies can be added with `add_dependencies()` function or implicitly with `target_link_libraries()`.

Comment: "then it's now nice". is it a typo or something? Also, libs in INSTALL dir are our own and available for developers only. We are not going to distribute them. They are statically linked to executables which are reditributed by packages. So, we prefer not really "install" our libraries on the system but keep them separate. Does it make more sense? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: An imported dependency won't be rebuilt.  From CMake's docs: "Dependencies added to an IMPORTED target are followed transitively in its place since the target itself does not build."  Also, `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` has nothing to do with building the target independently, it simply stops the target from being built as part of the `ALL_BUILD` CMake target.  Finally, the proper way to include another CMake project in yours is to use the `INSTALL(EXPORT...` command in the dependency, and then simply `INCLUDE` the exported `<target>.cmake` file in yours.  Run `cmake --help-command INSTALL` for details.