# How to prepend ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} to all files in variable?

Tags: cmake

I have project with subdirectories and I'd like to keep list of sources from each directory separated.

I have:

```
SET( SUBDIR_SOURCES
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/b.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/c.cpp
  PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

I'd like to have:

```
SET( SUBDIR_SOURCES
  a.cpp
  b.cpp
  c.cpp
  PARENT_SCOPE
)
some_magic_fuction( SUBDIR_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually write a small `CMakeLists.txt` for each subdirectory, which compiles all the files in that dir into a library.

In the parent directory's `CMakeLists.txt`, I add each subdir with `add_subdirectory( blah )`.

If you *must* have a variable as specified, the following should work (note, I haven't actually tested it):

```
MACRO( prepend_path _srcs _path )
    unset( _tmp )
    foreach( src ${_srcs} )
        list( append _tmp ${_path}/${src} )
    endforeach( src ${_srcs} )
    set( _srcs ${_tmp} )
ENDMACRO( prepend_path _srcs )
```

Call it thus:

```
prepend_path( SUBDIR_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
```

Comment: "I usually write a small CMakeLists.txt for each subdirectory, which compiles all the files in that dir into a library." I do that as well I find it easier to handle.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah - I should have been clearer.  That *is* a common (and correct) way to handle subdirs, but it's not necessarily wrong to do it the way the OP has suggested.  However, my point is that the code snippet shown is incorrect in several aspects.

Answer (score 2):

For `some_magic_function` to be passed the list of sources, firstly you'd need to avoid setting them in `PARENT_SCOPE` since they're not available in the scope of the subdir's CMakeList.

You also wouldn't need to pass the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` to the function, since it will be available inside the function, regardless of where the function itself is defined.

So you could do something like:

```
SET( SUBDIR_SOURCES a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp )
some_magic_function( SUBDIR_SOURCES )
SET( SUBDIR_SOURCES ${SUBDIR_SOURCES} PARENT_SCOPE )
```

and the function could be:

```
FUNCTION( some_magic_function SOURCE_FILES )
  FOREACH( SOURCE_FILE ${${SOURCE_FILES}} )
    SET( MODIFIED ${MODIFIED} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SOURCE_FILE} )
  ENDFOREACH()
  SET( ${SOURCE_FILES} ${MODIFIED} PARENT_SCOPE )
ENDFUNCTION()
```

Inside the function, `${SOURCE_FILES}` is `SUBDIR_SOURCES`, so we need to use `${${SOURCE_FILES}}` to get the actual file list.

Functions have their own scope, so since we want to replace the value of `SUBDIR_SOURCES` in the scope outside the function, we need to use `PARENT_SCOPE` when calling `SET( ${SOURCE_FILES}...`

For further info on these commands, run:

```
cmake --help-command set
cmake --help-command function
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally would also prefer functions with its own scope of local variables, but in your case I would suggest writing your own macro command.

So taking Fraser's code this would look like the following:

```
macro( set_subdir_sources )
    foreach( SOURCE_FILE ${ARGN} )
        set( SUBDIR_SOURCES ${SUBDIR_SOURCES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SOURCE_FILE} )
    endforeach()
    set( SUBDIR_SOURCES ${SUBDIR_SOURCES} PARENT_SCOPE )
endmacro()
```

Or with relative paths:

```
macro( set_subdir_sources )
    get_directory_property( _PARENTDIR PARENT_DIRECTORY )
    file( RELATIVE_PATH _SUBDIR ${_PARENTDIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
    foreach( SOURCE_FILE ${ARGN} )
        set( SUBDIR_SOURCES ${SUBDIR_SOURCES} ${_SUBDIR}/${SOURCE_FILE} )
    endforeach()
    set( SUBDIR_SOURCES ${SUBDIR_SOURCES} PARENT_SCOPE )
endmacro()
```

And just call:

```
set_subdir_sources( a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp )
```

Your parent `CMakeLists.txt` anyway has to know the `SUBDIR_SOURCES` variable. And this would have also the advantage that you can call it multiple times in the subdirectories's `CMakeLists.txt`.

But do you really need a `CMakeLists.txt` in a subdirectory that does not define its own target in the first place? I just would add the sources to your parent directories `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set( 
  SUBDIR_SOURCES
  SubDir/a.cpp
  SubDir/b.cpp
  SubDir/c.cpp
)
```

See also [CMakeLists.txt files for multiple libraries and executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673326/cmakelists-txt-files-for-multiple-libraries-and-executables)